# How to stop drop down menu from dropping when hovering under the "parent link"?

Tags: css, menu, hover

In this example the drop down menu shows up when you hover under the "parent link". I only want the drop down menu to show when I hover on the "parent link" and not under it. Is there any way to stop this?

codepen : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/timbeckett/pen/PoqbpXL)

code :

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu > li > a {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu ul a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could think of is to instead of using opacity:1 use display:none; and when you want to display it change it to display:block/flex/grid or the other way would be with javascript, by adding an event listener to the parent link and when mouseenter toggle the class of the animation to active or the name of the class and when the mouseleave toggle or remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

you have set hover to li in which the all the links come, You have to add hover to anchor tag and use `+` to make action on ul tag which is sibling of anchor tag.

```
.menu li a:hover + ul {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is your current code -**

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu > li > a {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu ul a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

## Modified Code

Just change `menu-ul` to `display:none` and when hover change it to `display:block`

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.menu > li > a {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}



.menu:hover ul{display: block;}

.menu li:hover ul {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}


.menu ul a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add `display: none;` on `<ul>`, then `display:block;` on `<ul>` when the parent is hovered.

```
 .menu ul {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none; /*dont display it yet*/
}

.menu > li:hover ul {
  display: block; /*dispplay ul on hover*/
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu > li > a {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.menu > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.menu ul a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
          
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```